# Fast bilinear interpolation on old iOS devices

Tags: ios, performance, interpolation

I've got the following code to do a biliner interpolation from a matrix of 2D vectors, each cell has x and y values of the vector, and the function receives k and l indices telling the bottom-left nearest position in the matrix

```
// p[1]                     returns the interpolated values
// fieldLinePointsVerts     the raw data array of fieldNumHorizontalPoints x fieldNumVerticalPoints
//                          only fieldNumHorizontalPoints matters to determine the index to access the raw data
// k and l                  horizontal and vertical indices of the point just bellow p[0] in the raw data

void interpolate( vertex2d* p, vertex2d* fieldLinePointsVerts, int fieldNumHorizontalPoints, int k, int l ) {

    int index = (l * fieldNumHorizontalPoints + k) * 2;

    vertex2d p11;
    p11.x = fieldLinePointsVerts[index].x;
    p11.y = fieldLinePointsVerts[index].y;

    vertex2d q11;
    q11.x = fieldLinePointsVerts[index+1].x;
    q11.y = fieldLinePointsVerts[index+1].y;

    index = (l * fieldNumHorizontalPoints + k + 1) * 2;

    vertex2d q21;
    q21.x = fieldLinePointsVerts[index+1].x;
    q21.y = fieldLinePointsVerts[index+1].y;

    index = ( (l + 1) * fieldNumHorizontalPoints + k) * 2;

    vertex2d q12;
    q12.x = fieldLinePointsVerts[index+1].x;
    q12.y = fieldLinePointsVerts[index+1].y;

    index = ( (l + 1) * fieldNumHorizontalPoints + k + 1 ) * 2;

    vertex2d p22;
    p22.x = fieldLinePointsVerts[index].x;
    p22.y = fieldLinePointsVerts[index].y;

    vertex2d q22;
    q22.x = fieldLinePointsVerts[index+1].x;
    q22.y = fieldLinePointsVerts[index+1].y;

    float fx = 1.0 / (p22.x - p11.x);
    float fx1 = (p22.x - p[0].x) * fx;
    float fx2 = (p[0].x - p11.x) * fx;

    vertex2d r1;
    r1.x = fx1 * q11.x + fx2 * q21.x;
    r1.y = fx1 * q11.y + fx2 * q21.y;

    vertex2d r2;
    r2.x = fx1 * q12.x + fx2 * q22.x;
    r2.y = fx1 * q12.y + fx2 * q22.y;

    float fy = 1.0 / (p22.y - p11.y);
    float fy1 = (p22.y - p[0].y) * fy;
    float fy2 = (p[0].y - p11.y) * fy; 

    p[1].x = fy1 * r1.x + fy2 * r2.x;
    p[1].y = fy1 * r1.y + fy2 * r2.y;
}
```

Currently this code needs to be run every single frame in old iOS devices, say devices with arm6 processors

I've taken the numeric sub-indices from the wikipedia's equations http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation

I'd accreciate any comments on optimization for performance, even plain asm code

Comment: Maybe you can use the DSP to achieve a speedup. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005147

Comment: It seems a reasonable, I'll take a closer look, thanks

Comment: The accelerate framework is available on iOS 4.0 and above, I'm re-writing my function to do some performance tests, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should not be causing your slowdown if it's only run *once* per frame. However, if it's run multiple times per frame, it easily could be.

I'd run your app with a profiler to see where the true performance problem lies.

There is some room for optimization here: a) Certain index calculations could be factored out and re-used in subsequent calculations), b) You could dereference your fieldLinePointsVerts array to a pointer once and re-use that, instead of indexing it twice per index...

but in general those things won't help a great deal, unless this function is being called many, many times per frame. In which case every little thing will help.

Comment: I've incremented the FPS using some compile time flags and moving my interpolation code to the main loop too. Thanks, appreciate it.

Comment: I'm still curious: how many times is the above called per frame? And have you tried using a profiler on your program yet? (You use "Instruments" -- it's VERY useful.)

Comment: The above code should be called at least 15.84 times per frame, as this is the smallest step simulation interval I can set for BulletsPhysics without getting things to move choppy, as my physic simulation is somewhat heavy

Comment: Whoa. While I've not done physics programming before, are you sure this is necessary? If your animation is running at say 30 frames per second, this results in the above function being called 475 times per second! Double that if you run at 60fps. Is it really necessary to model your physics more often than you update the screen? Of the 15 times you call it, only one of these will be reflected visually to the user. Unless you must run it that often in order for it to function properly, it'd be better to model your physics at a constant frame rate, like 30fps or 60fps.

Comment: Oh! You are right, it's 15.84 times per second for physics simulation step, and FPS varies from 28 to 60 FPS (many bodies, and just a few, respectively)

Comment: Okay, but while physics is done 15.84 times per second, is the function above called more often than that? Perhaps once per object in your scene? If so, that'd make sense why you'd want to optimize it.

Comment: This function is called once per body, with 15 bodies my FPS dropped to 28 in an iPod Touch 2G, affter I moved my code to the main loop agained a few FPS, the optimized using some compile time flags, and now my FPS are over 40 with 15 bodies. I guess it could be the other way, and there wouldn't be a need to move my code.